# How much luck from recoding an existing Λ character?

Tags: terra-battle

I ask this question as I am trying to empty the Pact of Fellowship pool, and am thinking of doing the same for Pact of Fate (because I want those Luck chests).

I understand that recoding a character allows you to inherit 100% of that character's luck, plus 20% from each of the monsters used to recode.

I also understand that recoding a character that you already have the Λ form of will add 5 Luck.

My question is: Is the additional luck just straight up 5, or do you also get a bonus from the luck of the just-recoded character?

Ex. Assume I have a Suoh Λ with 10 Luck. If I recode another Suoh with 50 Luck and monsters with 50 Luck each (so 50 + (50 * 0.2) + (50 * 0.2) = 70), will my Suoh Λ have 15 Luck (10 + 5[Existing Λ Recode bonus]) or 85 Luck (10 + 70[new Suoh Λ] + 5[Existing Λ Recode bonus])?

Answer (score 1):

> A Recoded character *will inherit 100%* of the original character's Luck value and *20% of the Luck values from the monsters* used in the recode.
>
> An existing "Λ" character will also gain an *additional* 5 Luck if the character is recoded again.

(Emphases mine.)

If I interpret the Terra Battle Wikia page on [Recode DNA](http://terrabattle.wikia.com/wiki/Recode_DNA) and [Luck](http://terrabattle.wikia.com/wiki/Luck) correctly, the current Recoded character should get 100% of the newly-Recoded character's Luck PLUS 5. So, in my example problem, it would be the second case ((10 + (50 + (50 * 0.2) + (50 * 0.2)) + 5) == 85).

Information from a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TerraBattle/comments/53bpzs/recoding_for_the_luck_stat/) also seems to bear this out. Will update this answer when I finally decide to try it out (which may be a long time seeing as I am thinking of emptying the Pact of Fate pool too).

EDIT: Can confirm that recoding a character again will add luck using (new base char boosts) + (monster 1 luck * 0.2) + (monster 2 luck * 0.2) + 5; it will not exceed the max 100 limit for recoded characters though.
Just did this with a Jaguna on top (+~103) of my existing Jaguna Λ (L 0.3).